# How to check whether a post exceeds 300 words

Tags: posts

I need to check whether a post exceeds 300 words or not. If it exceeds 300 words, then I have to provide a link to read more about the post.How can I do it? Please help me.I am new to word press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need to change the default EXCERPT length of your posts.

there are a couple of ways to solve this issue:

1. if you aren't familiar with PHP

Install this plugin at : http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

This will allow you to change the the excerpt length from the admin panel.

1. if you are familiar with basic PHP

Go to your functions.php in your theme at /wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/functions.php

Add the following code:

```
function different_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 200;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'different_excerpt_length');
```

You can change 200 to any number you want like 300.

As for showing your summary instead of the full post, you can follow the instructions from wordpress.com like so : http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I also add the 'read more' link,so that when I click on that link, I can view the full post

Comment: Hi i edited the post. You can try this post out: http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/

Comment: where should I call this function?

Comment: if you are referring to different_excerpt_length(), when you add_filter, the function is called when WordPress runs your theme. So that should work. Do make sure you add it to your ACTIVE theme :)

Comment: sorry, I can't follow you. I AM NOT UNDERSTANDING THE METHOD YOU ADOPT. can you please be clear. Actually I need to display only the first 300 word of each post in my home page. And under each post I need a read more link.so that when I click on that link I need to view the full post

Comment: http://bavotasan.com/2009/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/, this might be helpfull, for read more link, if you are in the loop just use the_excerpt with excerpt_length filter it will provide rad more link by itself

Comment: hi user1991, sorry I replied late. Do you still need clarification or did dot1 provide a good answer?